# dataframe create elements using index and row header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, multi-index

I can create an empty dataframe with multiindex row and columns:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

subr = [4]*4 
supr = [4]*4

subtable = [[i for i in range(1,r+1)] for r in subr]
suptable = [[i for i in range(1,r+1)] for r in supr]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(subtable), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(suptable))

def resolve(subs,sups):
  diff = len(subs)-len(sups) 
  if diff>0:
    sups = [0]*(diff)+sups
  elif diff<0:
    subs = [0]*(-diff)+subs
  else:
    pass
  
  for i, x in enumerate(zip(subs,sups)):
    if x[0]==3 and x[1]==3:
      return 'rdd'
    elif x[0]==3 and x[1]!=3:
      return 'vd'
    elif x[0]!=3 and x[1]==3:
      return 'hd'
    else:
      pass

  return 'value'
```

I now want to populate the dataframe using `resolve` so that for each element it takes the column and row header (which are both tuples) and then sets the element to some string. I can, obviously, do it by iterating through the dataframe. But is there a way to use some sort of transform?

Comment: What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: The output of the function is a string

Comment: Please provide a complete example with the function and the expected output given a small example input

Comment: @user19077881 su**B**table ≠ su**P**table ;)

Comment: @mozway please find example

Comment: I did a few edits for `resolve`. It pairs `subs` and `sups` (extending one if shorter); through `zip` . Going through each pair as soon as `x[0]` or `x[1]` or both are equal to 3 returns some string otherwise if 3 does not appear anywhere returns 'value'. By the way I tried `df.apply(lambda x:resolve(list(x.index),list(x.name)))` and I get lot of `NaN`s

Comment: In theory you can use numpy broadcasting to compare the items. However, given the small size of your dataset a loop might be much easier to set up. Do you always have the combinations in order (0, 1, 2, 3) or can it be arbitrary?